# Collection view tiling

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I am trying to have a scrolling collection view with 2 columns of images. The images in the end will be of different height, but same width to take up only half of the screen vertically, but as you can see, theer's a lot fo black space.

[image: Sample image]

Here is the code.

```
import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

```
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
@IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    if let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        let itemWidth = CGFloat(Int(view.bounds.width / 3.0))
        let itemHeight = layout.itemSize.height
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
        layout.invalidateLayout()
    }


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("imageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell!
    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    collectionView.registerClass(ImageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    return 10
}

}
```

And for the cell itself:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ImageCell: UICollectionViewCell{

var imageView: UIImageView!


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height))
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "defaultImage.jpg")
    contentView.addSubview(imageView)

    //fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

Comment: You need to look into the `minimumLineSpacing` and the `minimumInteritemSpacing` attributes of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. You can tweak these properties on your flow layout to get rid of the space. See the docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewFlowLayout_class/). You also need to make sure your item width will take advantage of the space available on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Use this delegate function

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                          layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
          sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

            CGSize screenSize=UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size

        return CGSizeMake(screenSize.width/2, yourheighteOfImage);
        }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                                      layoutcollectionViewLayout:UICollectionViewLayout,minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
       return 0.0
    }
```

Comment: Just return height of image here also